# How to implement code coverage into github android project (Travis CI, codecov)

Tags: android, code-coverage, travis-ci, codecov

I am now struggling with adding code coverage to my Android test project, can someone help?

https://github.com/zisean/CarbonContact-SCC-Group1

CI: Travis

Comment: Perhaps this example can help https://github.com/codecov/example-android

Comment: I've follow the instruction but travis failed https://travis-ci.org/zisean/CarbonContact-SCC-Group1/builds/155355497

Answer (score 1):

You can read the error [in this line](https://travis-ci.org/zisean/CarbonContact-SCC-Group1/builds/155355497#L1762), a permission denied.

You can fix it adding the next lines to your .travis.yml:

```
before_install:
 - chmod +x gradlew
```

Alternatively, you can add the exec-permission to your gradlew script via git like this:

```
git update-index --chmod=+x gradlew
```